# ACF Relationship field store custom values in an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on a ACF Block that uses the relationship field to choose posts in a CPT, this then displays content, the issue I am having is that we export pages etc to the live site and as the relationship field stores post IDs these are not the same on the live site. We use a custom field to store an unique number for every post.

So is there a way of storing the custom field values into the code of the page? One thought I had was to somehow loop through the post ids of the chosen posts and save the custom field value into an array stored in a text field - but I have no idea to how to achieve this or if this is the right way to go.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So if I'm good understand you want to loop posts by ACF custom field (post ID)?

Comment: Not quite, Its more that i need to use the custom field value to dislpay the data and not the post IDs as the post Ids cahnage from the staging site to the live one